# Convert Json format for Circle Packing Chart

Tags: javascript, json

I am plotting a chart and for that I want to convert the below json

```
var jsonArray = [{
            "tagValueName": "PCI",     
            "tagValueId": 1,
            "priorityAlertsCount": 20,
            "investigationAlertsCount": 140,
            "incidentAlertsCount": 100,
            "otherAlertsCount": 40
        }, {
            "tagValueName": "ABC",
            "tagValueId": 2,
            "priorityAlertsCount": 100,
            "investigationAlertsCount": 60,
            "incidentAlertsCount": 20,
            "otherAlertsCount": 20
        }];
```

But the chart requires data in below format

```
 var jsonData = [{
                "tagValueName" : "PCI",
                "type": "priorityAlertsCount",
                "count": "20",
            },
            {
                "tagValueName" : "PCI",
                "type": "investigationAlertsCount",
                "count": "140",
            },
            {
                "tagValueName" : "PCI",
                "type": "incidentAlertsCount",
                "count": "100",
            },
            {
                "tagValueName" : "PCI",
                "type": "otherAlertsCount",
                "count": "40",
            },{
                "tagValueName" : "ABC",
                "type": "priorityAlertsCount",
                "count": "100",
            },{
                "tagValueName" : "ABC",
                "type": "investigationAlertsCount",
                "count": "60",
            }];
```

How can I convert JSON from my format to the required format of the chart?
Please help as I am new to JS?

I want to plot a chart like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this jsbin](https://jsbin.com/kekotupono/1/edit?js,console).

```
var jsonArray = [{
  "tagValueName": "PCI",     
  "tagValueId": 1,
  "priorityAlertsCount": 20,
  "investigationAlertsCount": 140,
  "incidentAlertsCount": 100,
  "otherAlertsCount": 40
}, {
  "tagValueName": "ABC",
  "tagValueId": 2,
  "priorityAlertsCount": 100,
  "investigationAlertsCount": 60,
  "incidentAlertsCount": 20,
  "otherAlertsCount": 20
}];

var descriptionProperties = ['tagValueName', 'tagValueId'];
var nameProperty = ['tagValueName'];

function formatData(dataArray) {
  return dataArray.reduce(function(acc, item) {
    var formattedItems = Object.keys(item)
      .filter(function(key) { 
        return descriptionProperties.indexOf(key) === -1; 
      })
      .map(function(key) {
        var obj = {};
        var value = item[key];
        obj.type = key;
        obj.count = value;
        obj[nameProperty] = item[nameProperty];
        return obj;
      });
    acc = acc.concat(formattedItems);
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

console.log(formatData(jsonArray));
```

Basically you should have a look at basic array functions, such as [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) as well as the higher order functions [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) which I have used to transform the data in the way you needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to iterate through your array and then use `Object.keys` to iterate through the property of each object. If the key name contains `count` at the end of name, add this property to output.

```js
var jsonArray = [{ "tagValueName": "PCI", "tagValueId": 1, "priorityAlertsCount": 20, "investigationAlertsCount": 140, "incidentAlertsCount": 100, "otherAlertsCount": 40 }, { "tagValueName": "ABC", "tagValueId": 2, "priorityAlertsCount": 100, "investigationAlertsCount":60, "incidentAlertsCount": 20, "otherAlertsCount": 20 }];

var result = jsonArray.reduce((r, o) => {
  Object.keys(o).forEach(key => {
    if(/count$/i.test(key)) {
      r.push({tagValueName: o.tagValueName, type: key, count: o[key]});
    }
  })
  return r;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```